# Why can't perl locate mod_perl when I try to use SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Apache?

Tags: perl, soap, mod-perl

When the following code is executed, I get the error `Could not find or load mod_perl at C:\Perl\site\lib\SOAP\Transport\HTTP.pm line 741`, even though I successfully installed the module `mod_perl2`.

Code:

```
!#/usr/bin/perl 
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP; 
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Apache -> dispatch_to('WorldFunctions') -> handle; 
package WorldFunctions; sub new { bless {}, shift; }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: sorry : i mean mod_perl2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand this SOAP business that well, but it seems to me that you installed `mod_perl2` but the code needs `mod_perl`. Of course, for that to work, you probably have to go back to using Apache 1.x and I am assuming that is not a desirable option.

It would seem to me that you need [SOAP::Transport::HTTP2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SOAP%3a%3aTransport%3a%3aHTTP2), but that modules seems to be in a little bit of a mess.

In any case, the [README for Apache2::SOAP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Apache2-SOAP/README) seems to hold the clue:

> This is a replacement for `Apache::SOAP` (and `SOAP::Transport::HTTP`)
>   designed to work with the CPAN version of `mod_perl` 2. It is intended
>   as a temporary measure until the `SOAP-Lite` distribution
>   implements this functionality. Note that the provided modules
>   (`Apache2::SOAP` and `SOAP::Transport::HTTP2`) do not clash with
>   any modules of `SOAP-Lite`.

Given that the description above was written in 2008, are you sure `SOAP::Lite` has not implemented that functionality?

Comment: thnx for the comment, i'll try it and i'll tell my answer

Comment: i can't install Apache2::SOAP, i have an error :  cannot opendir c:\Apache\lib : No such file or directory at C:/Perl/site/lib/Apache2/Build.pm